# Am I required to install feeder grounds when I replace main panels?

Tags: electrical, grounding

I have a 30 or 40 year old electrical system that only has 3 service wires to each sub panel, two hots and a neutral. The wires coming out of the breaker box on the pole are direct bury to 3 different buildings on this property. No electrical service wire to any building has a 4th buried ground wire connecting back to the box on the pole. Each building has a ground rod supplying the ground to each sub panel.

If I want to replace the breaker box on my meter pole, do I have to run a fourth ground wire to each building or is this system grandfathered in and is it safe? I guess it has been okay for 40 years. Did they really used to wire systems like this?

To rephrase my question for clarity, I do not want to replace any sub panels, I actually want to replace the electrical (main) panel right under the meter which is on the utility pole outside, that feeds all my sub panels. I want to be able to add one more sub panel going to another planned building, and the existing electrical panel has no more room for any additional breakers. It would not be a problem to add a ground from a new panel on the pole to the new building, it would be more difficult to add a ground to the other three buildings that each have sub panels that are fed by only two hots and the neutral and have a grounding rod at each building's electrical wiring entrance. Also, there are only short pieces of PVC conduit that take the wire below ground level. The direct Bury wire then goes to each subsequent building, absent any conduit, and then comes up out of the earth and enters another PVC conduit prior to coming out of the earth, so there is no metal conduit involved.

Answer (score 4):

Generally no you wouldn't be required to upgrade the feeders. If it was legal when installed it generally remains legal, but this really isn't a Electrical Code issue, "grandfathering" is a local Ordinance issue. If the local law requires you upgrade feeders when upgrade panelboards then you would need to.

The NEC is a standard written by the NFPA, and becomes enforceable in whole or part as adopted by local authorities with jurisdiction. Your Country, State, County, or City may adopt in whole or in part, and can write many pages of additional rules.

Response to edit: Upgrading the Service panel has no different trigger that the NEC would require upgrading all the feeders.

Yes this used to be normal, before sometime around 1990 the NEC treated feeders to detached buildings the same as Service feeders, with the service neutral bonded to the building grounding electrode system. Some localities were slow to adopt this.

Also the current version of the NEC generally requires that if ground rods are used as a electrodes then 2 rods at least 6' apart are required, many local ordinances require further spacing. Even though no required I would upgrade your systems if possible, particularly in a 3 wire feeder scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

While grandfathering per se is not really the concern of NEC, this scenario is explicitly allowed by code, as long as the feeders were previously installed in accordance with an older version of the code.

In NEC 2020 allowance for this can be found in 250.32(B)(1) Exception 1. (Other versions should have it somewhere similar).

Please note carefully the prohibition on any "continuous metal path" connecting a building served with such a feeder to any other building. This is because plumbing or communications cables, etc would generally be grounded at the other building, and in this setup would be able to act as an alternate neutral path, so there is a risk of significant current trying to flow though such connections.

This is because if neutral is bonded to ground in each building, and these metal paths are also grounded in each building, current can flow into the grounding system or GECs, into this metallic connection, to the other building, back to panel where it is connected to neutral again, and an then flow back on that other building's feeder or service neutral, as applicable. See figure 3 on of the 2008 IAEI [article about this code change](https://iaeimagazine.org/2008/september2008/two-buildings-common-service-grounding-requirements/) for a diagram showing this alternate neutral path.

That risk is the main reason this approach was phased out and is not longer allowed for new installations. Imagine say a natural gas pipe ending up as an alternate neutral return path. That would be asking for a problem!